# I can't access a div in order to style it with css

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, react-bootstrap, display

I can't access a div to style it. but i got not a single error in console not even a warning.

I tried with `!important` but it was useless.

I know bootstrap has something to do with that but I don't know what to do at this point.

Could somebody help me? That would be nice.

particulier.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

import Image from 'react-bootstrap/Image';

import picture from '../img/picture.jpg'
import ExampleCarouselImage from '../img/ExampleCarouselImage.png'

function Particulier() {

    const imageUrls = [
        ExampleCarouselImage,
        ExampleCarouselImage,
        ExampleCarouselImage, ExampleCarouselImage,
        ExampleCarouselImage,
        ExampleCarouselImage, ExampleCarouselImage,
        ExampleCarouselImage
    ];

    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);

    // Fonction pour gérer le clic sur une div
    const handleDivClick = (index) => {
        setActiveIndex(index);
    };

    return (
        <Container fluid id="particulierContainer">

            <Row xs={12} md={12} className=''>

                <Col xs={12} md={6} className='text-center'>
                    <Image id="imgParticulier" src={picture} thumbnail={true} width="50%" />
                </Col>

                <Col xs={12} md={6} className='text-center align-self-center'>
                    <h2>Nous vendons au details des produits professionnels bla bla</h2>
                    <h2>Voust trouvez toutes nos offres ici</h2>
                    <a>lien page facebook</a>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <Row xs={12} md={12} className='d-flex justify-content-evenly text-center my-5' >
                <h1>Voici les marque que nous vendons</h1>
            </Row>

            <Row xs={12} md={12} className='d-flex justify-content-evenly text-center my-3' >
                {imageUrls.map((imageUrl, index) => (
                    <Col key={index} xs={12} md={4} lg={3} className='mx-1 my-2 azer' style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => handleDivClick(index)}  >
                        <Image className='imgMarque' src={imageUrl} thumbnail={true} width="100%" />
                        <div className={` ${index === activeIndex ? 'acacher' : ''}`}>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                        </div>

                    </Col>
                ))}
            </Row>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Particulier
```

Comment: Can you clarify? where and  which div and witch style ?

Comment: The <div> with the className 'acacher' behaves as expected. I attempted to style it using display: none, but it doesn't work. I inspected it while clicking on one of the <div> elements, and the className 'acacher' does indeed appear and disappear when I select one or another <div>.